# How could I improve this List iteration with a Stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm attempting to count the number of times an Int is seen in a field within a List of Objects.

This is the code I have

```
TreeMap<Integer, Double> ratings = new TreeMap();
ArrayList<Establishment> establishments = new ArrayList<>();

double one = 0;
double two = 0;
double three = 0;
double five = 0;

for (Establishment e : establishments) {
    if (e.getRating() == 1) {
        one++;
    }
    if (e.getRating() == 2) {
        two++;
    }
    if (e.getRating() == 3) {
        three++;
    }
    if (e.getRating() == 5) {
        five++;
    }
}

    ratings.put(1, (one / establishments.size()) * 100);
    ratings.put(2, (two / establishments.size()) * 100);
    ratings.put(3, (three / establishments.size()) * 100);
    ratings.put(5, (five / establishments.size()) * 100);
```

yet it isn't ideal, if more ratings are added (say 20+) then you'd have a bunch of doubles being created, and it's not maintainable.

I know I could do something with a Stream if I had a list of ints, say

```
listOfInts.stream().filter(i -> i == 3).count()
```

yet this is a list of objects, which contain an int and I need to calculate the number of ratings == X in that list of objects.

so pseudocode for what I need:

> establishemnts.getAllRatings().stream().filter(ratings -> ratings ==
>   3).count()*

* Repeating for each of the rating types 1 - 5

** There is no getAllRatings - I guess that's the issue I'm trying to solve)

Comment: You example doesn't contain case handling rating == 4. Does such rating not exist, or you wanted to filter it out by specifying rest of ratings which you are interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can implement getAllRatings using streams to get list of ratings

```
List<Integer> attributes = establishments.stream().map(es -> es.getRating()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So to get count of ratings for a particular rating you can use

```
establishments.stream().map(es -> es.getRating()).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().filter(ratings -> ratings == 3).count()
```

If you want to get the ratings count/percentage for all ratings then please use the code in @Marek's answer

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
Map<Integer, Double> ratings = new TreeMap<>();
List<Establishment> establishments = new ArrayList<>();
establishments.stream() 
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Establishment::getRating, Collectors.counting()))
              .forEach((k, v) -> ratings.put(k, (double)v/establishments.size() * 100));
```

Which will use [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) with [`Collectors::counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--), that will create a `Map` consisting of the count of the ratings, then use `forEach` to add them the `TreeMap`

Or, as suggested by VGR, an even more elegant use of [`Collectors::collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<Integer, Double> ratings =
establishments.stream()
              .collect(
                       Collectors.groupingBy(Establishment::getRating, 
                       Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), c -> c * 100.0 / establishments.size())
               ));
```

Which will directly create the `Map` without having to create a `Map`, stream over it again, and then collect to a `Map` again

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but instead of a forEach, I would replace Collectors.counting() with `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), c -> c * 100.0 / establishments.size())`, so the stream expression would actually return `Map<Integer, Double>`.

Comment: @VGR That is even more elegant! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

Using more or less only streams:

```
List<Establishment> establishments = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Double> ratings = establishments.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Establishment::getRating, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), 
                                  e -> 100.0 * (e.getValue() / establishments.size())));
```

Comment: Don't know why it wouldn't. I've actually typed it in in Intellij and it works. The `getKey` method is from the `Map.Entry` object.

Comment: @Wayneio What is return type of `getRating` in `Establishment`? For instance if it is double to represent values like 3.5 stars then you would need to declare resulting map as `Map<Double, Double>` instead of `Map<Integer, Double>`.

Comment: Oh my bad, it was declaring map as TreeMap

Answer (score 0):

To get `TreeMap<Integer, Double> ratings` you can use stream api with [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`summingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) as a downstream:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Double> ratings = establishments.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Establishment::getRating, TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.summingDouble(v -> ((1.0 / establishments.size())* 100))));
```

And to count the number of times:

```
long count = establishments.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getRating() == 3)
        .count();
```

Comment: Your summingDouble expression always returns the same value;  it does not use `v` at all.

Comment: @VGR I don't need to use `v` there. `summingDouble` returns number of occurrences each rating / list.size() * 100. This is exactly what OP needs

Comment: @VGR By the way, `Collectors.counting()` under the hood works the same way, but using `summingLong(e -> 1L);` instead

Answer (score -1):

In loop you can sum values:

```
for (Establishment e : establishments) {
    // Get old value OR set to "0"
    Double rating = ratings.getOrDefault(e.getRating(), 0);
    // increase rating (counter)
    ratings.put(e.getRating(), rating + 1);
}
```

And calculate average at the end:

```
// Calculate part of equation which is not changing in loop
int size = establishments.size() * 100;

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : ratings.entrySet()) {
    // Calculate average
    Double average = entry.getValue() / size;
    // Add it to the map
    ratings.put(entry.getKey(), average);
}
```